# Another - Must declare the scalar variable @TDate Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have searched long and hard on this issue and can't come up with anything that works! Please can you help me? What am I doing wrong to cause this error? Must "declare the scalar variable @TDate" I am updating two dates - dob and transfersate. In this case transferdate in the sql table and TDate a date value from a date control.

```
Using SQLCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE member SET "DOB = @DOB, transferdate=@TDate WHERE mid =" & MID, SQLCon)

    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@transferdate", SqlDbType.Date)
    SQLCmd.Parameters("@transferdate").Value = TDate

    SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB)

    i = SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using
```

Comment: I am updating a record. I keep getting the error "Must declare the scalar variable @TDate when I execute. Yet, it is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you sql query you refer to the variable `@TDate` in the bit `transferdate=@TDate`. 
You add SQLParameters to your cmd, but the parameter you add is called `@transferdate`.

Try changing this bit of code here:

```
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@transferdate", SqlDbType.Date)
            SQLCmd.Parameters("@transferdate").Value = TDate
```

to this instead:

```
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@TDate", SqlDbType.Date)
            SQLCmd.Parameters("@TDate").Value = TDate
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I was pulling out what was left of my hair!! Tested to the hilt and it all works. Thank again!